# How to change background color every second with (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Take the current second and change the background color.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {View,Text} from 'react-native'

export default class ChangeColor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    }
  }

  tick() {
      this.setState({
        date: new Date()
      })
    }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000 //1 second
    )
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{/* backgroundColor=[(0 corresponds to white, 1 black, 2 blue, 3 green, 4 pink, 5 red, 6 purple, 7 yellow, 8 gray and 9 lilac). */}}>
        <Text>{this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</Text>
        <Text>changing color automatically every second</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please get rid of all the "help-me!" in your post and add more description for what you are hoping to get

Comment: Please add some text to your post not just code, explaining the problem you are facing. Review this for how to ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/adequate-pretzels

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const colors = [
  'white',
  'black',
  'blue',
  'green',
  'pink',
  'red',
  'purple',
  'yellow',
  'gray',
  'lilac',
];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setValue((v) => (v === 9 ? 0 : v + 1));
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: colors[value] }]}></View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not much familiar with react-native but the code below will work for simple react js component, it changes the color of the div background and heading every second.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Home extends Component{
     constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = {
               bodyColor: 'grey',
               headingColor: 'white'
          }
     }

     // Function to create random rgb values
     generateRGBColor(){
          let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          let val = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
          return val;
     }
     
     // setting interval to change state every 1000 mili-second
     componentDidMount(){
          this.interval = setInterval(() => {
               this.setState({
                    bodyColor: this.generateRGBColor(),
                    headingColor: this.generateRGBColor()
               })
          }, 1000);
     }

     // unmounting for preventing memory leakes.
     componentWillUnmount(){
          clearInterval(this.interval);
     }

     render(){

          return(
               <div className="Home" style={{backgroundColor: this.state.bodyColor}}>
                    <h1 style={{color: this.state.headingColor}}>Hello React Js</h1>
               </div>
          )
     }
}
```

Comment: it will work if you replaced div with View and h1 with Text and here is your complete example for react-native : https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/random-backgroundcolor

Comment: Kindly mark tick if it is the solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of function like this one:

```js
function getColorBySeconds(date){
  let seconds = date.getSeconds().toString();
  if(seconds.length > 1){
    seconds = seconds.slice(1);
  }
  switch(seconds){
    case '0': 
      return "white"
    case '1': 
      return "black"
    case '2': 
      return "blue"
    case '3': 
      return "green"
    case '4': 
      return "pink"
    case '5': 
      return "red"
    case '6': 
      return "purple"
    case '7': 
      return "yellow"
    case '8': 
      return "gray"
    case '9': 
      return "lilac"
    default: 
      return "white"
  }
}

console.log(getColorBySeconds(new Date()))
```

Just add it in your style object like this : `style={{ backgroundColor: this.getColorBySeconds(this.state.date)}}`

And correct the syntax so it will fit react:
`getColorBySeconds = (date) => {...}`